# PHP - Unable to access certain elements with Simple XML

Tags: php, xml, rss

Does SimpleXML only give access to elements with certain names? I've been trying to get the publish date from a few rss feeds which is possible when the date is contained inside of a pubDate tag, but I'm having trouble with feeds that hold their dates inside of a tag called "dc:date"

```
<dc:date>2013-12-12T22:30:46+00:00</dc:date>
```

When I print_r, the items looks like this

```
$rss = simplexml_load_file($source_url);

[0] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => NEWS: Mayday Parade post 2014 Vans Warped Tour announcement video
                        [link] => http://www.altpress.com/news/entry/mayday_parade_post_2014_vans_warped_tour_announcement_video
                        [guid] => http://www.altpress.com/news/entry/mayday_parade_post_2014_vans_warped_tour_announcement_video
                    )
```

No sign of dc date. is this SimpleXML behaviour? How could I possibly access the date, the feed I'm accessing is this one: http://www.altpress.com/rss

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the [SimpleXMLElement::children documentation](http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexmlelement.children.php) states, you must explicitely provide namespace if you want to query any of the non-default (e.g. NULL) namespace children.

As an example consider:

```
$xml = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?> 
<rss xmlns:dc="my.dc.urn"> 
    <channel> 
        <item> 
            <title>Tom And Jerry</title> 
            <category>Comicbook</category>
            <dc:date>2013-12-12T22:30:46+00:00</dc:date>
        </item> 
    </channel> 
</rss>
';

$rss = simplexml_load_string($xml);

$item = $rss->channel[0]->item[0];

print_r($item->children());
//prints out "title" and "category"

print_r($item->children("dc", true));
//prints out "date" within the "dc" namespace (e.g. "dc:date")
```